# Active Directory or LDAP Attribute for Android Contact Photo

Tags: android, active-directory, ldap

Is there an Active Directory or other LDAP attribute that can be populated with an image so that it will be displayed in an Android contact listing?

I am part of a team that is looking into populating contact photos into Active Directory. We have identified the appropriate attributes that Outlook uses for this (thumbnailPhoto and jpegPhoto is what I am planning on using), but whenever I search for one of our test users on my phone using the standard Exchange directory integration, the directory search pulls their contact information (email, phone number) as expected but the contact photo itself is just the standard blank head-shot.

Does anyone know if what I am trying to accomplish is even possible, and if it is, how?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Nope, and the project ended up getting tabled so I haven't really looked into it any further.

Comment: Sad to hear that... I'll make sure to post the answer here if I find it! Yes for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I promised if i'd find the answer i would share it in this post. It seems that the attribute needed to share the picture is Photo and it needs to be a byte[].

[Source](https://github.com/weisserd/LDAP-Sync/blob/master/src/de/danielweisser/android/ldapsync/client/Contact.java)